# How to change xcom in Airflow to accomodate large data?

Tags: airflow

I am using the following code in my Airflow operator:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook

class HttpToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(BaseOperator):
  template_fields = ['endpoint', 'data', 'headers', ]
  template_ext = ()
  ui_color = '#f4a460'

@apply_defaults
def __init__(self,
             endpoint,
             project_id,
             table_id,
             data=None,
             headers=None,
             auth=None,
             http_conn_id='http_default',
             *args, **kwargs):
    super(HttpToGoogleCloudStorageOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.table_id = table_id
    self.http_conn_id = http_conn_id
    self.method = "GET"
    self.endpoint = endpoint
    self.headers = headers or {}
    self.auth = auth
    self.data = data or {}

def execute(self, context):
    http = HttpHook(self.method, http_conn_id=self.http_conn_id)
    self.log.info("Calling HTTP method " + self.endpoint)
    response = http.run(self.endpoint, self.data,  self.headers,auth=self.auth)                            
    self.log.info("Got response")
```

Unfortunately the data returned is too large (about 5k) to fit in the standard xcom and I get this error:

**{taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - (_mysql_exceptions.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'value' at row 1")**

Is there a way I can tell http_hook to use a different xcom, or (even better) not use xcom at all?  I have looked around and I do not see a solution.

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Edit: Here is how I call the operator.  Note that nowhere do I specify xcom.

```
query_load_task = HttpToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
  task_id="query_load_task",
  endpoint=endpoint,
  project_id="my_gcp_poroject_id",
  table_id="dataset.table",
  data=None,
  auth=(username, password))
```

Comment: I don't think you can use xcom for such large objects. Keep in mind the xcom size its limited by the record size in the metadata database.

Comment: Right, I did not want to use xcom, and specifically created an operator to avoid this.  But the stack trace from http.run leads to it.  Could you tell me how to avoid it?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to store data to a system designed for such (*e.g.: the file system, AWS S3, Azure, etc.*) and instead return a unique identifier to reference the location of the data, for the file system this would likely be the full path (*e.g.: `/tmp/acme_response_20200709.csv`*) that way you leverage the best of both the storage system and your database.

If you add your code I'd be happy to take a crack at writing up some psuedo-code as an example.

Comment: I edited my question to add the full operator code.

Comment: That's the operator, can you share how it's using the XCom for your process?

Comment: That's the thing, I am not specifying xcom anywhere.  I edited the question to add how it is being called.